# Issue with VS2008 Solution, '' Is not Declared occurring a lot

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, migration

I just received a VS 2005 Solultion which I converted to 2008, which went fine.

Now I am trying to do some more coding but running into this error.

Lets say I create a new class called "siteFunctions", and try to run a method from this in the code behind and try to build the solution I get the following error

Type "siteFunctions" is not declared.

Now keep in mind this shouldnt be an error at all because the actual page itself loads fine, just VS has the issue with it ?